# how to add Roles and Permission in Rails even it's already build by devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

Working on Devise rails Project application  for rental stuff for the last two months, and now the project has to be changed as it already shipped

as my project email me as change route

"I have decided that we will go for a purely B2B play. So private individuals will not be allowed to list equipment to rent out only verified hire centres/hardware stores will be able to list equipment to rent out.
Private individuals will, however, be able to create a profile and make bookings through the platform just not rent out  from their own equipment/tools."

So My question is should I add new Column in the User like

Roles and Permission in the Devise User Column:

User (individuals),

Administrator (Our staff),

Company.

or use a gem like rails-devise-pundit or cancancan into the project, even this project has already built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can do this by using [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) gem.

Basic Steps to implement:

1. import gem into Gemfile
2. create a ability file by using the below command

```
rails g cancan:ability
```

3. define the accesses like below.

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    alias_action :create, :read, :update, :destroy, :to => :crud
    if user.super_admin?
        can :access, :rails_admin   # grant access to rails_admin
        can :dashboard              # grant access to the dashboard

        # Accss Level to Models


        can :crud

    end

  end
end
```

See more details for [Gems documentation](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [rolify](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) gem.

It's very easy to use and you can add several roles, and assign multiple roles to a user. With this, you can avoid adding new column to your user's table.

Here's how a you can assign a role to a user:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.add_role :admin
```

Verify if a user has a role `admin`:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.has_role? :admin
=> true
```